# How to normalize periods in elastic search query (such that JJ Abrams == J.J Abrams)?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need it so that words with periods inside them are equal to the non-period variant.

I see there's a section in the docs about analyzers and token filters but I'm finding rather terse and am not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [char filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html) to eliminate the dots, like this for example:

```
PUT /no_dots
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "my_mapping": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            ".=>"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_no_dots_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "my_mapping"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_no_dots_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And to test it `GET /no_dots/_analyze?analyzer=my_no_dots_analyzer&text=J.J Abrams` returns:

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "JJ",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 3,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "Abrams",
         "start_offset": 4,
         "end_offset": 10,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 2
      }
   ]
}
```